# Deep-links to my app from twitter - not working

Tags: android, android-intent, twitter, deep-linking, intentfilter

I have the following intent filter in my manifest to accept deep-link urls:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

    <data android:scheme="http" />
    <data android:scheme="https" />
    <data android:host="www.example.com"/>
    <data android:host="example.com"/>
    <data android:pathPattern="/path.*" />

</intent-filter>
```

Everything works great when tapping on links such as:

- http://example.com/path
- https://www.example.com/path
- http://example.com/path/something
- https://www.example.com/path?something=1

However - in Twitter, URLs are automatically shortened to something like this:

[image: shortened twitter url example]

*(sorry for pic - SO won't let me post a shortened link example... wth?)*

This URL is then resolved into the real URL when the user hits the link - however(!!), at this point once the URL is resolved into one that matches the above examples, android no longer seems to care about my intent filter and the URL is opened in a browser.

How can I resolve this so that URLs to my app from twitter properly open my app (or at least open the app picker)?

Comment: Have you tried getting Twitter to shorten "https://www.example.com/path?something=1" - since you know that this intent filter works. Let's try determine if it's your deep link or if it's the shortening

Comment: When the link is not shortened, everything works as expected

Comment: Hmm... so maybe it's being resolved in the browser BEFORE the Android system can attempt to handle it, and the redirect doesn't behave like a deep link

Comment: Yeah, I assumed that's the case, but was hoping for some workaround I could do from my end

Comment: Maybe try to look at Twitter's documentation on this, since it's their "middle man" link: https://dev.twitter.com/cards/mobile/deep-linking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct — with App Links, Android checks the *actual URL being opened* to see if any app is registered to handle it. If the URL is shortened (assuming the shortened domain itself is not registered, which is obviously the case with `t.co`), then subsequent URLs reached via redirects are not considered. iOS Universal Links work exactly the same way.

On Android, you have two options:

1. Put a custom URI scheme redirect on your destination URL. Then when the shortened link resolves, your user will end up in the app. Of course, you'll also need [something like this](https://blog.branch.io/technical-guide-android-deep-linking-uri-schemes/) to handle the app-not-installed situation. This is how we do it for Android at [Branch.io](https://branch.io) (full disclosure: I'm on the Branch team).
2. Show a deep-linked CTA button/link/smart banner on the destination URL. This is how things **must** work on iOS for apps like Twitter and Facebook, but on Android you still have the custom URI scheme option so this is less ideal.